# What does it mean to calculate a relation's quotient set (the set of all of equivalence classes)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

The set in question: T = {(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)}.

I am confused what it means by this, and I haven't found any resources online that helps explain this to me well enough. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  The quotient set is the set of equivalence classes.  In your case, assuming T is the relation for the set {a,b,c}, nothing is related to anything else, so the quotient set consists of singletons

Comment: To consider the quotient you need an equivalence relation(Probably $T$) and a set. If we assume the set was $\{a,b,c\}$ then the quotient is $\{[a],[b],[c]\}$ cause they do not relate with anyone but themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Given a set such as $S=${$a,b,c$} and an equivalence relation on it, such as $T$,

the **equivalence class** of an element, say $a$, is the set {$x\in S|(a,x)\in T$} of what is related to $a$.

For the relation $T=${$(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)$}, the equivalence class of an element, say $a$, is simply {$a$}.

($b$ and $c$ are not related to $a$.)

The **quotient set** is the set of all equivalence classes.

The quotient set of $T=${$(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)$} is simply {{a}, {b}, {c}}.

Comment: [This on-line resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) should help